# Convert specific UTC timezone to local timezone

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, utc

Okay, so I have been struggling with this problem for to many hours now. What I want to do is to convert "Brasilia Time (BRT) -0300 UTC" into user's local timezone. How can I do this using javascript? I've also tried some javascript libraries like moment.js but still no luck.

Comment: See this question for an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: Incidentally, the wording in your question makes no sense: there is no such thing as a "UTC timezone", UTC *is* a timezone. What you have there is a timezone string which includes the relevant offset from UTC.

Comment: Well, yeah, I should have said UTC offset +300. But still, how can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize javascript date to a particular timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone)

Comment: See the dup link, and consider using moment-timezone with the `"America/Sao_Paulo"` time zone.  If you need more help than that, you'll have to show some code.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center.

Comment: how did you use moment.js? can you provide some code? I am sure it is possible with MomentJs library

Answer (score 0):

You do `time.clone().tz('Yourlocalzone')`. See also: http://momentjs.com/timezone/ for full documentation.